# Junkyard planet trash distribution?

Tags: internal-consistency, planets, gravity, geography, orbital-mechanics

So, I've got a planet that's basically a junkyard. It's just one big junkyard. People from various space-faring societies dump all the crap there that they don't want to deal with. Derelict spaceships, obsolete tech, that sort of thing. And because the people doing this are lazy, what they basically do is just haul a big space barge close enough to the planet's gravity well, cut all the garbage loose, push it just over the edge of the well, and let it fall.

So my question is, assuming the trash isn't getting permanently trapped in orbit, and assuming both the trajectory and the exact point in space from which the garbage is released are both random, would the places the garbage falls be random too? Would there be an equal distribution over the entire planet's surface, or as the trash collects over thousands of years, would it start to pile up more in some places then others? Would it start to accumulate a whole lot around the equator, but barely any at all near the poles? Would things like mountain ranges or ocean currents influence this at all?

Update: Because everyone was asking, the reason there even is a junkyard planet is simply because humans are lazy. Various corporations and space governments figured out that they could just dump a ton of metal on a planet, and after about a hundred years, an eyeblink in space time, desperate folk would move there and begin setting up their own small-scale recycling operations, purifying the metal, lifting it back up out of the gravity well, and selling it to the companies again for a pittance. It takes a while but it's the cheapest and laziest possible way to recycle things on a massive scale.

Comment: Sounds like *Soldier (1998)*.  Anyway... where the incoming stuff lands depends on the where the space barges comes from.  If from a polar direction, then it could land anywhere; if from an equatorial orbit, then somewhere near the equator; etc.  Since it's falling from space, mountains and oceans have no impact.

Comment: There is no "Close enough" to a gravity well. It's a function of velocity and location.

Comment: The premise is utterly flawed, though, since metal is 100% recyclable, and the strong, lightweight alloys needed for space travel aren't cheap.  Thus, you'd recycle it.  And space travel itself is *expensive*.  Much simpler (I mean **much** simpler) to just drop stuff that's too expensive to recycle stuff into your own star.

Comment: @RonJohn : A society with free, limitless energy might not need to recycle anything - just make everything you need from scratch.

Comment: #1 free, *limitless* energy is impossible.  #1 e=mc^2 -> m=e/c^2, which means that you need a **lot** of energy to make mass.  **LOTS**.  Recycling your unobtanium is a lot simpler.

Comment: Gotta go with RonJon here. Nearly free and nearly limitless energy is nice, but recycling, or simply disposing junk into the nearest star makes more sense in energy and time than going across the galaxy to a junk planet.

Comment: @Willk Then presumably you can just turn your waste into energy instead of carting it off to some planet.

Comment: If you need a circumstance wherein such a planet would be useful, consider the possibility that the planet's use as a junkyard is stipulated in a contract between nations instead of for strictly practical reasons. Maybe the planet is supposed to be a midden for future archeologists, and cultures want to leave their legacy there. There are plenty of reasons people (among other creatures) do things impractically.

Comment: Since "*humans are lazy*", we'd shoot the stuff into the *nearest star*, not haul it half way across the Quadrant...  But while humans are lazy, a lot of humans still need jobs, and Mega Corps don't want to spend precious credits to haul stuff half way across the Quadrant, when for less money the junk would be brought to the space version of Chittagong Ship Breaking Yard, where 200,000 Bangladeshis make a pittance recycling ships.

Comment: Does the planet have an atmosphere? This makes quite a huge difference. (If it doesn't then all of the junk will either stay in orbit or impact the surface with very high velocity, leaving craters; if it does then most of the junk will burn up, but some fraction could reach the surface intact.)

Comment: A junk planet could make sense if you have weak engines but some sort of hyperdrive that is very easy to use but is only capable of moving you to a point of equal gravitational potential.  Given such a constraint the junkyard planet might actually be easier to reach than one's own star.

Comment: The only way I an make sense of this junkyard scheme is if it's a dumping ground for dangerous waste that is not allowed to be disposed of anywhere else. E.g. ships with leaking reactors, biological infestation, insane AI's, etc.

Comment: Does the space travel in your universe limit the approach to the planet?  With Star Trek style warp drive you can move at FTL speeds everywhere.  In the Star Wars system there are hyperlanes and most travelers will enter the system from the same location.

Comment: One thing - Junkyards aren't just somewhere to dump stuff you don't want - they're usually businesses that make their money by stripping the useful/valuable bits off machinery like cars, recycling the recyclables and disposing of the bits too dangerous to recycle. They're not landfills, which is (I suspect) what OP was actually suggesting the planet would be.

Comment: Instead of dispersing the trash, it may be simpler to dump the entire giant container on the planet. Containers are cheap, so for your rich but lazy megacorps, this would be good. The container can somewhat shield the junk from reentry heat (assuming atmosphere) and final impact. And the future desperate scavengers will have an easier time with a few giant piles than with crushed, half-disintegrated trash dispersed across literally millions of km²

Comment: If they have the energy to carry it to another star system, they have the energy to de-orbit it into their star.

Answer (score 16):

[The distribution of impact craters on the Moon is random](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1966MNRAS.132..413F). I believe the same can be said about Mercury, another crater-ridden body in our solar system. They got their craters from asteroids and comets that struck them randomly throughout the ages.

If the drop trajectories over your planet are really random, so will be the impact regions. If you still have doubts, a couple hours simulating this on Kerbal Space Program should solve the problem for you in a very practical manner.

Answer (score 7):

The initial falling is pretty well covered by the other answers, so this will focus on the other question in the OP.

> As the trash collects over thousands of years, would it start to pile up more in some places then others?

Many of the processes would apply to trash on Junkyard the same way that they apply to dirt on Earth.

**Precipitation**

If you wanted there to be a variety in its distribution, you could add weather that would prevent some trash from making it to the surface, or dissolve trash, creating a climate-like distribution of trash. For example, if your planet had acidic oceans, the patterns of accelerated trash decay would form in the same way that patterns of precipitation form on Earth, with less precipitation corresponding to less disintegration, and thus more trash. The oceans themselves would only contain trash that could survive their acidity.

For example, if Junkyard had Earth's geography, trash on the Western side of the Rockies would receive a lot more acid rain than trash on the opposite side, analogous to how California receives a lot more rain than Nevada.

**Geological Activity**

If the Junkyard planet is geologically active, subduction zones might swallow up a lot of trash, and the areas where new crust is made would be briefly bare. Also, the way trash reacts to lava could cause areas near volcanos to have unusual concentrations of specific types of trash

**Weathering from Wind**

Additionally, if certain latitudes have faster wind than others (comparable to the winds around Antarctica here on Earth), that trash would erode faster (on a very slow time scale, but still), and would have a tendency to settle around the belt instead of inside of it.

**Glaciers**

I'm sure there are more creative ways to incorporate glacial erosion, but at the very least, if someone dropped a comet onto the planet, its chunks might move like glaciers, carving out valleys behind them.

For processes that wouldn't apply to Earth:

**Tidal Locking**

If the planet orbits around a star, you might want to make it tidally locked, causing trash on one side to melt, and causing trash on the other side to accumulate. Additionally, dumpers may prefer one side or the other to avoid the heat of the star, or to get its energy, depending on which side you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the pattern would indeed be random, if the drop-off process is as haphazard as you suggest.  It's just that if the planet is used as often as you suggest, such a random set of flight patterns could get dangerous. You could have ships heading in to make a drop interfering with each other's flight paths.  SOME process wold likely emerge, even if it's only getting on the radio and saying "Hey this is the USS Macawber, if we don't hear from anyone in a half hour, we'll be making a drop run around Planet Junkyard".

I wouldn't be surprised if some governing body stepped in and set up flight paths, if only to make sure that some of the trash DOESN'T end up in orbit, or missing the planet entirely and causing a flight hazard.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, but I don't think it would be "All over the planet".

Most of it would fall along the equator, well assuming normal orbits (equatorial orbits).  If you were dropping it in random orbits then it would be random.  But if you drop in the plane of the planets rotation (again equatorial) then it would be concentrated at the equator.

Obviously if your orbit determines where it will de-orbit, unless you dump it with a good amount of velocity.

Anyway now that everyone is done splitting hairs about what I said, and I do stress the OP never defined an "orbit".

**UPDATE** (just an idea)

I think a better premise then a Junk planet is a graveyard planet.  From an energy standpoint it doesn't make much sense to take the effort of flying garbage to a planet and then slowing down and dumping it, when you can just shoot it into the nearest star.

A better idea as I said is a graveyard planet, what I mean by that is something like this:

[image]

The US military bone yard.

For the most part we keep this place pretty clean but a whole planet used for this purpose and it wouldn't be worth the energy to clean it up.  The purpose would be for things like military treaties that limit the use or number of certain ships, for example.  It could also be used for deprecated/obsolite equipment. Some of this equipment even though obsolete could still be better then some factions have. And then there is always the use as a parts yard, for post production equipment. You know to keep some of the old stuff fit and running you sacrifice some of them for parts.

After a few centuries the place would start looking pretty dumpy.

And most of this stuff would have been, safe'd by having the engines or fuel removed before being place for long term storage.  So it wouldn't be like you could just land there and sneak off with a star destroyer.  Besides you could always have the place guarded by some orbital defense satellites and what not.

Even if you want to leave the military aspect out of it, I could see a mega corp taking a small, arid and mineral poor planet and using it for this purpose.  Basically a giant Scrap/Junk yard.  There may be valuable parts that take specialized manufacturing, or dangerous material that needs specialized handling and recycling facilities.  So they take the only thing the planet has to offer a somewhat breathable atmosphere and gravity and use that.  Being arid its no good for food production, being poor in minerals its no good for mining.  The dryness of the place would be good for preventing corrosion etc.  Then they import old ships and equipment, cannibalize them and export replacement parts and scrap metals.

But in this case, and if you have valuable infrastructure that you don't want destroyed, you probably wont want stuff just falling from orbit randomly over the planet.  You might have a corridor that is setup for reviving bulk scrap metals.  Stuff that has no salvageable parts as the energy to deorbit it "gently" would not be justified.  This could be around the equator (see what I did there).

Couple this with prison/slave labor, and I would believe it was possible in some distant future.

Comment: #1 There's no such thing as a "normal" orbits.  #2 It also assumes that stars exist only in the planet's equatorial plane.

Comment: it doesn't matter if there is a sun or not, it matters which way the planet rotates `plane of the planets rotation`  there is a relationship between the orbit, tidal forces, and the planets rotation that can have a small effect on the orbiting bodies.

Comment: I didn't mention the sun in my comment.  All I said was "planet's equatorial plane".

Comment: The premise is "assuming both the trajectory and the exact point in space from which the garbage is released are both random". There is no force generated from a rotating planet that will move an object from a polar orbit into an equatorial orbit. If you assume this premise, do you still say it will be grouped at the equator?

Comment: @Samuel - why would you think that I assume that when I clearly stated `If you were dropping it in random orbits then it would be random`  In fact your assuming by `trajectory and the exact point in space from which the garbage is released are both random` that means a random orbit.  The most efficient orbit is one in the equatorial plane.  A random trajectory, could mean the garbage was dumped on a random trajectory, not that the dumping agent was on a random orbit.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix It's confusing because you're answering a question that wasn't asked. Your answer boils down to "random orbital insertions == random orbits and non-random orbital insertions == non-random orbits". Is that right? "The most efficient orbit is one in the equatorial plane." That's not correct. If you were launching the trash from the surface of this planet, I would agree, but you're not.

Comment: Why would we think that you assume it? Because you wrote, "*Most of it would fall along the equator, well assuming normal orbits.*"

Comment: That is a world away from this `There is no force generated from a rotating planet that will move an object from a polar orbit into an equatorial orbit. If you assume this premise`  I'm not assuming the premise that a planets rotation will change a polar orbit.  Only that if and I said if you dump it in an equatorial orbit it will not be all over the planet.

Comment: Further, I specifically said if you dump it in a random orbit then it will be orbit. And as I mentioned its you guys `points finger` that is doing the assuming, because you are assuming a random trajectory means a random orbit.  This `and assuming both the trajectory and the exact point in space from which the garbage is released` does not say anything about an orbit, and I stress this part "garbage is released"

Comment: "*equatorial orbits, which are more efficient*" for **ground launches**.  Not for arriving from another star.

Comment: That is splitting hairs, anyway...  There I removed "more efficient" happy.  As I said you can have an equatorial orbit and still release the garbage in a random trajectory.

Comment: The *new* answer is quite good.

Comment: That's because I have the best words, lol.  No i was just thinking from a practical standpoint, I could see a mega-corp doing this.  I was at work and didn't have a lot of time on my hands, rewriting some encryption stuff and what not.

Answer (score 0):

Does it rotate? If so, the trash would be more likely to pile up on the plane of rotation, which for an earthlike setup is the Tropics of Cancer to Capricorn. However, I think you need to think through the whole low orbit thing. If people were being at all careless in their dumping, there would quickly be a sheath of debris orbiting this planet such that it'd be difficult to land there, and it'd be constantly bombarded with impacts. This would be a tough place to live.

Comment: Trash would pile up in whatever orbit people dumped it in. You might be thinking of the fact that planets are mostly in the orbital plane, but recall that ring systems for planets depend more on the planet's rotation than its orbital plane. Uranus for example has rings that are almost perpendicular to the orbital plane because that's how Uranus rotates. And all that is only that way as a leftover from formation, not because it's a better orbit.

Comment: You're absolutely right; rotation would trump orbit hands' down. Clarifying my post.

Comment: Oh, still, the plane of rotation doesn't really come into it unless they're launching from the surface (as it's a cheaper orbit to get to from the surface). Being in orbit at all is assuming people dump their trash at orbital velocities.

Comment: Any ship that's of less mass than the planet itself needs to orbit unless it's just going to dump somewhere nearby and wait a few hundred years for the gravity well to suck it up. If you're orbiting and dropping, the trash is going to come out in a line based on both your trajectory and the planet's rotation, assuming it's not just a compacted singular block. Which part am I missing here?

Comment: "If you're orbiting and dropping, the trash is going to come out in a line based on both your trajectory and the planet's rotation" - No, the planet's rotation doesn't enter into it, **only** the orbital parameters. A ship only needs to enter an orbit if it plans to stay. Would you agree it's feasible for a ship to approach a planet directly, drop its trash, and then make a slight course adjustment to miss the planet entirely? In that case it wouldn't even need to slow down from interplanetary speeds to orbital speeds nor waste the energy slowing its trash down in the same fashion.

Comment: That's very true. And I suppose with the halo of trash already there, it's best to just throw it and run.

Answer (score -1):

As @ArtisticPhoenix said, it will likely have a bell curve distribution centering on the equator or some other line near the equator.  That is because most planets lie in their star's plane of ecliptic and have a spin that corresponds roughly with the plane of the ecliptic.  Most stars are on or near the galaxy's plane of the ecliptic and their spin's correspond generally to the galaxy's plane.

This isn't 100% but the majority of the ships dumping stuff should come in with a least cost approach near the equator.

Even if ships do not come in on an equatorial plane, since the planet is spinning, their trash has a good chance of crossing the equator and will otherwise be distributed around the planet.  If you have ships from different stars coming in at different angles and directions, almost all of their dumps will cross the equator.  This will make the distribution higher as you approach the equator.

Comment: "*The majority of the ships dumping stuff should come in with a least cost approach near the equator.*  Why?  There are a whole lot of stars in the Northern Hemisphere, so what's to stop barges from coming in from a polar direction?

Comment: @RonJohn, first, many of the "stars" you see are actually galaxies.  Also, get into an area with dark skies and look at the Milkyway or find a picture on the internet (but that's not nearly as good).  Even if all of the "stars" you see are actual stars, look at how many more come from near the Milkyway's plane of the ecliptic.  Also, in the second part of the question, I address the situation if they aren't in a near equatorial orbit.

Comment: The Milky Way is -- from some point on the Earth at some time of year -- at every angle from almost 0° to 90°.

Comment: The premise is "assuming both the trajectory and the exact point in space from which the garbage is released are both random". Are you saying the premise of the question is wrong?

Comment: A drop of trajectory would only be less costly by bwing close to the equator if the starting trajextory is already within the same plane as the equator. Even in our own solar system that is rarely true, since each planet's orbit around the sun has its own plane.

Comment: @Renan, the dropping ship doesn't need to hit an exact equitorial orbit for my answer to be true.  It just has to hit an orbit that isn't purely polar.  As long as the various flight paths don't take the majority of the dump ships over the poles, the equator will be crossed more than any other zone on the planet.  Over time, the distribution would be heavier over the equator.

Comment: I understand, but even that depends on approaching trajectory. Think of Uranus, Pluto and Charon.

Comment: @Samuel, I think that the drop points won't rigorously random.  I think that they will be biased toward equatorial.  This is based on the fact that there are more stars along the plane of the Milkyway.

Comment: @Renan, Yes.  I'm just saying that the preponderance will be near equatorial.  The farther away they are coming from, the less likely they will be on a polar orbit.

Comment: `The farther away they are coming from, the less likely they will be on a polar orbit.` That does not make sense. Once gain, it depends on approaching trajectory. Polaris is over 346 light years away from us. Aldebaran's declination is 16 degrees and it is 66 light years from us. If a ship from each were coming ou way, which one do you think would be more likely to provide a polar flyby?

Comment: @Renan, I was assuming that if you have enough energy to make it reasonable to ship junk to a planet in another star system that the civilization would be incredibly large.  In that case, if you look at the distribution of stars in even the local arm of the Milkyway, most are oriented near the galactic plane.

Comment: @ShadoCat Wait, are you assuming most planetary equators line up with ecliptic planes of solar systems which in turn line up with the galactic plane? Look no further than Earth for a counter example. Even within our own solar system planetary equators range from near zero to near ninety degrees rotation from the ecliptic.

Comment: @Samuel, I'm saying that, in general, planet equators line up near their system plane and that, in general, system planes tend to line up with the galactic plane.  Since the O.P. did not specify that there was anything odd about the planet or its system, I assume that it is similar to most.

Comment: "*in general, planet equators line up near their system plane and that, in general, system planes tend to line up with the galactic plane*" [This statement is easily falsified](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/205738/do-solar-systems-typically-spin-in-the-same-direction-as-their-galaxy). Solar systems have no better chance to align their planes with the galaxy than our own solar system did. Our system isn't an anomaly with its near perpendicular angle to the galaxy.